# 12c and ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I've inherited databases/tables that contain over 1000 columns in a single table that need to be migrated into an Oracle 12c database. Is there anything inherent to 12c that could help us with overcoming the 1000 column limit (such as partitioning the table in a certain way)?  Unfortunately normalizing the table is not an option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what kind of data is it? there is not that many meaningful reasons to have that wide table.

Comment: If you're migrating to an Oracle database, applying some sanity to the data model should probably be high on your priority list anyway. What sort of entity has more than a hundred attributes? You're making a significant change to your system anyway - "normalizing" the table must be an option.

Answer (score 6):

Max of 1000 columns always has been in Oracle. Only thing you can do is to split the columns to multiple tables and join them. A query can return more than 1000 column. Just tested 8160 worked, more returns ORA-00913: too many values. Unfortunately you can't create a view from the query because it has the same 1000 column limitation as a table.

Also be aware that Oracle can hold only up to 255 columns in single block so there are certain consequences when a table has more columns.

Answer (score 1):

There is still a limit of 1,000 in 12c

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76.htm#REFRN0043

It's a long shot, but you could look at using a JSON datatype to allow you to effectively store more atomic values in a single column. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246

Answer (score 1):

And still in the newest release 19c there is the limit of 1,000.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76

And in the release 18c also:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76